# remove line break using AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am facing some problem regarding my bash script.

Below is my bash code :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /root/Msgs/TESTNEW/new

file=myfile.txt

var1=$(awk '(NR==30){print $2}' $file)
var2=$(awk 'NR>=38 && NR<=39' $file)
var3=${var2// /+}

curl "http://<server_ip>/power_sms/send_sms.php?username=<user>&password=<pass>phoneno=$var1&text=$var3"
```

This scripts purposed is for reading in a range of line in particular file(for ex:myfile.txt).Then it will put the content of the file into some variable(var1,var2).
After that,the variable will be called into the curl functions.

The problems start when the content of the file have spacing in every new line.This making the curl not functioning as it do not accept white space character.I have manage to replace the spacing into plus symbols.But whenever there is new line,it will have spacing  rather than having plus symbol.

Some of the output is as below:

```
hi+there.hopefully+you+can+get+this+email+which+are being+send+as+sms.
```

Can someone help me?Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using linux then this will substitute newlines to +

`awk '{printf "%s+",$0} END {print ""}'`

or with sed

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/+/g'`

Comment: +1 for answering the real question

Comment: NOTE: on OS X this won't work as sed is to an older spec. Use `gsed` if you need the full GNU sed functionality. So, `brew install gsed` to install it via Homebrew.

Answer (score 21):

```
awk NF=NF RS= OFS=+
```

Result

```
hi+there.hopefully+you+can+get+this+email+which+are+being+send+as+sms.
```

Comment: Why isn't this at the top?

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: For the solution with **awk**, you are looking for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}{gsub(/\n/,"",$0); print $0}' myfile.txt
```

Another method to strip all newlines from your file:

```
tr -d "\n"
```

An example:

```
tr -d "\n" < myfile.txt > myfilewithoutnewlines.txt
```

Comment: Or just `awk '{printf "%s" $0}' <file`.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing this the wrong way. You need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your text  to get a truly universal solution:

When you do this and use a text like this:

```
This is 
a test 
text
```

you end up with this: `This+is+%0d%0aa+test+%0d%0atext`.

You can use `curl` to do this:

```
curl -G -d username=<user> -d password=<pass> -d phoneno=$var1 \
       --data-urlencode text@myfile.txt \
       http://<server_ip>/power_sms/send_sms.php
```

For more info, see `man curl`.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to point out in @Sirch sed code you can replace the aforementioned, "+" with any other separator. I hope this helps a few beginners!

example

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/   /g' #puts 3 spaces between the result
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` statement gets rid of the pesky Windows carriage return as well:

```
sub(/[\n\r]+/,"+",$0)
```